# Write function that accepts pointer variables and and assigns values from file to struct in C

Tags: c, eclipse, function, pointers, struct

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Temba Bavuma 10.05 Hashim Amla 5.04Dale Steyn 16.78
```

I am given a struct in separate header file that looks like:

```
#ifndef APARTMENTS_H_
#define APARTMENTS_H_

struct apartmentData
{
    char ownerName[30];
    char ownerSurname[30];
    double tariff;
};
typedef struct apartmentData ApartmentData;

#endif
```

I have to use the following function to assign three different apartments the values from the text file and the function should not produce output:

```
void readMetadataFromFile(ApartmentData *data1, ApartmentData *data2, ApartmentData *data3);
```

The apartments are assigned their values through this function in my main.c. There is a different header file for the function and the apartment struct. The function has its 'own' .c file.

I am not sure how to add the values to the different apartments. I understand how to open a file and read in the values. I do not understand how to assign three apartments their appropriate values through a function with this struct and pointer. I have to use this function prototype as is. Can someone please help?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you fail? As it stands the question tends to be to broad.

Comment: In your typing, all the data was on a single line.  Is that really how the data is presented in the file, or does the file actually have three lines?  You've run the `5.04` into `Dale` with no space; is that really how the data is presented?  It can be processed with `fscanf()` as shown, but it isn't the way I'd expect to see the data.  IMO, you'll need an extra function which reads one record from the file, and you'll pass the three different pointers in three separate calls to the one function.  To do otherwise would be ludicrous repetition.

Comment: Show the definition of the `readMetadataFromFile()` function

Comment: That data actually looks like that in the file, one line, no commas and the one is 5.04dale does not have a space.

Comment: void readMetadataFromFile(ApartmentData *data1, ApartmentData *data2, ApartmentData *data3)
{
 
 FILE *afPtr;

 

 if ((afPtr = fopen("apartments_metadata.txt","r")) == NULL)
 {
       puts("File could not be opened");
 }
 else
 {


  while(!feof(afPtr))
  {
          fscanf(afPtr, "%s %s %d", data1);
  }
 }
}

Comment: Above is what I tried and obviously did not work the data looks strange to me but it is what I was given and I am not allowed to change it or  edit the function prototype in any way. The function will be called in the main to assign the apartments their different data.

Comment: @Brood Post the code along with your question by editing it. When posted as comment it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to read from the text file into the `ApartmentData` variables using the `void readMetadataFromFile(ApartmentData *data1, ApartmentData *data2, ApartmentData *data3);` function you could do

```
void readMetadataFromFile(ApartmentData *data1, ApartmentData *data2, ApartmentData *data3)
{
    FILE *fin=fopen("apartment.txt", "r");
    if(fin==NULL)
    {
        perror("Error");
        return;
    }
    fscanf(fin, "%29s %29s %lf", data1->ownerName, data1->ownerSurname, &data1->tariff);
    printf("\n\n%s %s %lf", data1->ownerName, data1->ownerSurname, data1->tariff);

    fscanf(fin, "%29s %29s %lf", data2->ownerName, data2->ownerSurname, &data2->tariff);
    printf("\n\n%s %s %lf", data2->ownerName, data2->ownerSurname, data2->tariff);

    fscanf(fin, "%29s %29s %lf", data3->ownerName, data3->ownerSurname, &data3->tariff);
    printf("\n\n%s %s %lf", data3->ownerName, data3->ownerSurname, data3->tariff);

    fclose(fin);
}
```

You should also check the return value of the `fscanf()` to see if the assignments were successful.

In this case, each of the `fscanf()`s should return `3` which is the number of successful assignments.
If it isn't `3` some error has occurred.

The `->` operator is used to access the contents of a `struct` via a pointer to it.

Edit: [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) pointed out that there are chances of overflow with `fscanf()`.

Since the sizes of the string members of the structure is `30`, use `"%29s"` while reading into them allowing for the `\0` character denoting the end of string.

Otherwise if a string of size greater than that of the character array is supplied, memory out of bounds of array will be overwritten, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: This is a lot simpler than what I had. Thank you very much

Comment: `fscanf(fin, "%s %s %lf" ,,,` has similar buffer overflow problems as the now obsolete `gets()`.  Better to limit input with `fscanf(fin, "%29s %29s %lf" ...`

Comment: @chux Thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If it lools like this `Temba Bavuma 10.05 Hashim Amla 5.04 Dale Steyn 16.78` (with a space between 5.04 and Dale)
I advise, you make another function

```
void fill(ApartmentData *data, File* f)
```

and call it inside `readMetadataFromFile` 3 times like this

```
fill(data1,f)
fill(data2, f)
fill(data3, f)
```

In this function. After you read the values in `char* name, char * surname` and `double tariff` (that you know how to do), assign

```
data->ownerName=name;
data->ownerSurname=surname ;
data->tariff=tariff;
```